# State of art of prime numbers distribution

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, open-problem

I was reading some questions about prime numbers posted in latest days and a question came to my mind:

> What is the state of art of the research into prime numbers distribution?

I read then several other questions ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69628/riemann-hypothesis-and-prime-number-distribution), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741418/distribution-of-prime-numbers-can-one-find-all-prime-numbers) for example), all interesting but no one really fitting: is there any recent new from researchers in this field? Any milestone or breakthrough discovery related to it in the latest few years?

Is approach to this open problem changing in time? Thanks to somebody in particular?

On one side I do not check regularly such *high* topics, on the other I seriously risk not to understand properly some of what I ask. This was meant to be a sort of soft question, hope it's on topic. Any links to (*soft* or not) dissertations over the *recent evolution of this study* is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are asking for a survey of the modern developments in understanding prime numbers, and I believe it would be best to start by looking at some expository papers.

Here is a paper by Granville title [Analytic Number Theory](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrinceComp.pdf) which appears in the Princeton companion to mathematics. It starts off very slow, and I think it is a great place to start. (Alternatively, here is another expository paper by Granville title [A good new millennium for prime](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimesICM.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

For a partial answer see:

http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes

Everything there is certainly state of the art.