# How to describe the error of the asymptotic approximation of the prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

I've been reading about this asymptotic approximation of the prime counting function $\pi(x)$:$$π(x)=Li(x)+O(\sqrt{x}\ log(x))$$
What does this tell me about the error of this approximation? If the error were just $O(\sqrt{x})$ I would know that if I multiply $x$ by four I would roughly double the error. Is there an as simple interpretation for $O(\sqrt{x}\ log(x))$?

Comment: See also the comments to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326721/riemann-hypothesis-and-prime-distribution/3326734#3326734).

Answer (score 1):

$\log x$ is very small compared to any positive power of $x$, so a good interpretation is "just a bit larger than $O(\sqrt x)$".